# Can find Project Panel in Macromedia Flash MX

Tags: flash, macromedia

i am trying to review flash for our game thesis in school. i am trying to read a pdf file about flash and i am trying to do the examples listed in the notes.

but i can't find the location of the project panel. Well i know where it lies if i used my own laptop with the prescribe flash in it. (FYI, i am using the company's installed flash in my assigned computer. i am an ojt here and since i finished their project early, i dont do much here anymore) so as pass time, i study flash for our thesis (my boss doesn't mind. He believed learning is good)

The flash installed here i thinks is a bit old version. and honestly, i can't apply what i am learning since the setup is way different.

So does anyone knows where the project panel is located? or if it is close, where can i open it? The company is using a Macromedia Flash MX by the way, i hope someone could point it to me.

i apologies for this very weak question.

MisaChan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the splash screen (where it has options to create new documents) and click **new project**. PS the project panel is a piece of garbage.

Down the track when you understand the Flash UI a little better, look into [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/) for a great application to manage your project.

Comment: my problem is that, in this, flash, when i clicked on the new in file as said in the notes, it just automatically creates a new document, no extra window is appearing wherein i know, there should be one. :(

Comment: could it be possible that there is a bug in the application? or is it not installed properly? i tried pressing Shift+F8 but nothing happens. same goes in window-project. there is no project in the windows. :(

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure if Macromedia Flash has a project panel.. Considering it's 1 million years old.

Comment: its that old??? my Macromedia Flash at home has a project panel, and its the latest one too. but the flash installed here i guess is a very old version. :(

Comment: What's interesting about your macromedia flash being the latest version is that Adobe actually took over flash in 2005.

Comment: what i meant was the macromedia flash i used at home is the last and latest macro-media flash, i also have the adobe flash installed. those were working properly and can be easily understood. But the flash installed in the company where i am having an on-the-job training is like the flash from way back the old times. :( i find it hard to apply what i am reading here although i understand the notes i have. I guess the flash here is a trash and too old to be applied and used as my training in using flash. i dont even think someone here still uses this.

Comment: Yeah, you might wanna have a chat to someone in the company and point out that the software is extinct.

Comment: i guess that would be the best idea :) thanks sir @Marty Wallace  for your time :)

Comment: @MisaChan not sure, but as far as I remember the Project panel was added in Flash MX 2004 (Flash 7), not Flash MX (Flash 6). If you're using Flash MX you're stuck to actionscript 1.0. I would recommend using FlashDevelop since you can compile actionscript 2.0, if you choose to do so, or actionscript 3.0 (using the free/opensource FlexSDK). You can still use Flash MX to create design assets and animations you can later load and control from actionscript in FlashDevelop